# How to Use COLUMN_COUNT in Jaspoer report

Tags: jasper-reports

I am using "COLUMN_COUNT" predefined Variable in Column Detail component and able to display the numbers also. However, the number is getting reset in the next page. Please advise how to restrict reset type in next page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `REPORT_COUNT` variable instead of `COLUMN_COUNT`.

Comment: Thanks.i am able to display the numbers now using report_count